# What's the convention to name the 3 different types of model that exist in ASP.NET MVC? (controller input, controller output and persistence)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, naming-conventions

What's the convention to name the 3 different types of model that exist in ASP.NET MVC? (controller input, controller output and persistence)

Visual Studio, while MVC 3 scaffolding, puts a "Model" suffix to every model class but I'm not sure this is a good approach not to differentiate the type of model.

A secundary question I'd like to ask is how to name these 3 different types of model. I'm not the model that enters the view is called view-model. The persistent can be called persistence model. But what about the controller input model?

Comment: what do you mean by "controller input model"? You mean what gets passed to the HTTP POST action? It's the same as the "output model". (e.g the ViewModel)

Comment: @RPM 1984: By controller input I mean the model that is used as a parameter of the Action while using model binding. For instance... Let's say your action have three parameters: A, B and C. You could then define a model class that would contain these 3 properties and then let MVC to perform databinding. This is controller input model

Comment: oh this is so good question particularly because whole asp.net mvc infrastructure forces you to use the same model for input and output.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use `*ViewModel` for the Controller output model and `*Form` for the Controller input model.

For persistence (domain models/entities) I don't use any special naming convention.

Comment: I personally liked this naming convention. Unless someone else point me to a better direction, I'm following your solution

Answer (score 3):

I rather like the way it's given in [here](http://codebetter.com/robashton/2011/06/13/finding-a-balance-with-asp-net-mv/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20CodeBetter%20%28CodeBetter.Com%29). It distinguishes between Controller input models which query and those which call service layers (repositories etc). I'm starting to adopt the following:

- Use `*ViewModel` for Controller output models.
- Use `*Query` for Controller input
  models where you are just en-capsulizing parameters used in a query.
- Use `*Command` for Controller input models which call Service layers.

A couple of examples:

```
// Example of Controller query input model
public ActionResult Search(SearchProductsQuery query)
{
    ProductSearchViewModel searchView = query.ExecuteWith(productsRepository);
    return View(searchView);
}

// Exmaple of Controller command input model
public ActionResult Create(CreateProductCommand command)
{
    if (command.Validate(this.ModelState))
    {
        var newProduct = command.CreateProduct();
        productRepository.Add(newProduct);
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: linked article and consquently value of your answer is simply stunning ! must read. best written mvc article i've read so far...

Answer (score 1):

I have a `User` domain entity, which has a `ChangePassword` method that accepts a `ChangePasswordInput` class and returns a `ChangePasswordResult` class. `ChangePasswordInput` is also used as controller input and view model of the `ChangePassword` view (form), and `ChangePasswordResult` is used as view model of the `ChangePasswordSuccess` view.

Comment: which of these models (*Input / *Result) do you use then as the model of the view? if you choose just one of them (which you have to) you dont have much support from htmlhelper for example. i found this answer to overcome this [http://forums.asp.net/t/1597367.aspx/1?Can+you+have+a+different+input+and+output+model+in+a+view+] but it is still a little bit clumsy :(

Comment: @Boris Bucha: Depends on the view. For the `ChangePassword` view (form) I use `ChangePasswordInput` as model, and for the `ChangePasswordSuccess` view I use `ChangePasswordResult`.